# SAS - Add origin table name as a column in report

Tags: sas, report

I have an output table that contains 300+ variables from 30 different tables that are joined by UNION, which is used for modelling. I have created a macro that creates a report with a number of statistics, such as mean, min/max values etc. using this output table. I am trying to add a column to the report that details which table(s) the variables come from. I say table(s) as some of the variables are shared across different tables. I want to avoid having the same variable in the report multiple times as the statistics are the same irrespective of what table the variable comes from. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: You probably need to be more specific to get an answer here.  If you want to know which dataset an OBSERVATION came from then use data step to combine the records and use the INDSNAME= option on the SET statement.  Data step with SET statement is probably better for stacking data than using SQL with UNION anyway.

Comment: Please provide some example data showing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of UNION consider using a DATA STEP and then use the `INDSNAME` option instead.

```
data want;
set sashelp.class sashelp.cars indsname=source;
source_dataset = source;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would loop over each of the `union` datasets and just put the table name and variable names into a compiled dataset. You probably have all the table names in either a macro list or typed out, so you can just add a few more lines of code to run `proc contents` on each of those to compile a full list of table and variable names. Note that like your example, there will be duplicate variable names that you can modify after the table is compiled:

```
** create different tables **;
data height; set sashelp.class(keep=name height); run;
data weight; set sashelp.class(keep=name weight); run;
data sex; set sashelp.class(keep=name sex); run;

** put your datasets into a list either manually or dynamically **;
/* manually */
%let ds_list=height weight sex; 

/* dynamically -- be careful to include only tables in your union */
proc sql noprint;
    select MEMNAME
    into: ds_list separated by " "
    from sashelp.vmember
    where libname = "WORK" and memname not in ("SASMACR","FORMATS");
quit;

%put &ds_list.;

** loop over each table to put the table name and variables in a dataset **;
%MACRO get_names(ds_list);
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&ds_list.));
    %let ds = %scan(&ds_list.,&i.);
    proc contents data = &ds. noprint 
        out=names_&ds.(keep=MEMNAME NAME rename=(MEMNAME=SOURCE_DATASET));
    run;

    proc append data = names_&ds. base=full force; run;
%end;
%MEND;

%get_names(&ds_list.);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using the following:

Create table with source tables.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE    SOURCES AS
SELECT          NAME
                ,MEMNAME
FROM            DICTIONARY.COLUMNS
WHERE           LIBNAME='LIBNAME'
ORDER BY 1,2;
RUN;
```

Join to my stats table.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE    STATS_NEW AS
SELECT          memname AS TABLE_NAME,a.*
FROM            STATS a
LEFT JOIN       SOURCES b
ON              a.name = b.name
GROUP BY        a.name
ORDER BY        a.name;
QUIT;
```

Transpose data and add in comma separators.

```
DATA            STATS_TRANSPOSE (drop=TABLE_NAME);
LENGTH          INPUT_TABLES $1000;
SET             STATS_NEW;
BY              name;

RETAIN          INPUT_TABLES;
IF              FIRST.name THEN DO; INPUT_TABLES=TABLE_NAME; END;

IF NOT          FIRST.name
THEN DO;
            INPUT_TABLES=CATS(INPUT_TABLES,', ',TABLE_NAME);
END;
IF              LAST.name THEN DO;
IF              name IN ('FIELD1','FIELD2')
THEN DO;        INPUT_TABLES='ALL'; END;
OUTPUT;
END;
RUN;
```